# Gridview with FileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

I have a gridview that shows an image as part of one of its columns.  In Edit mode, I would like to let the user have the ability to upload a new image file, so I am using the FileUpload control in the edit portion of the template.

I have an event to capture this i believe:

```
        protected void GridVew1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {          
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/hardware/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
        }
    }
```

I do not know how to call the control correctly though... How is this functionality coded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to handle the **RowUpdating** event instead of **RowUpdated**. Then you need to find a reference to the FileUpload control on that row.

**IMPORTANT:** *You need to know the ordinal position of the column where the control is located. In my example, I set it to 0, assuming it is the first column.* Otherwise, you would need to through the Cells collection to find it.

```
protected void gridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    FileUpload fileUpload = row.Cells[0].FindControl("fileUpload1") as FileUpload;
    if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/hardware/" + fileUpload.FileName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the file is uploading perfectly.  I see the Cells[0], but it seems to find the control no matter what I set this to... not sure why.

Comment: How to do this for datagrid?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are doing here you will have to find the control in the row

so in VB some thing like this

```
    Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating

      Dim aRow As GridViewRow = Me.GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    dim xFileUpload as fileupload = CType(aRow.FindControl("FileUpload1"), FileUpload)

    xFileUpload. save file etc etc etc 

End Sub
```

Caveat - if this is wrong I would love to see a better way to do this!